# Money supply change per block

Tags: ether, etherscan, totalsupply

How can I deduce how much money, in total, was created and burnt in a particular "finalized" block?

For example, using [etherscan](https://etherscan.io), I notice that most blocks
have "burnt" exceeding "reward", so it seems most blocks are reducing the money supply.
My understanding is, however, that the money supply usually grows, so I looked for blocks
with "reward" exceeding "burnt", like block #16195877 (compare to the more usual #16195876).
But, since rewards are mostly (entirely?) paid with gas fees, I still can't decide
whether the money supply is increasing in these blocks.

So, can someone just break down these two blocks in terms of the money supply?
Most importantly, where does the money supply increase within a block?

Comment: How do you define "money supply", eth supply?

Comment: @DrGorilla.eth Yes, eth supply, or the total eth (the sum over everybody's wallets).  I'm not asking for the total though, just the change in it (which should be easier and more directly calculable from the transactions, right?).

Comment: have you checked tools like https://beaconcha.in/burn ? Since the merge, issuance has been slightly negative (or oscillating around 0), rn at (mean) -1 eth/min for instance

Comment: @DrGorilla.eth Yes, I looked at "beaconcha.in", but it too doesn't clearly show me how the money supply is changing.

Comment: @DrGorilla.eth Basically, as I see it, each transaction should burn a gas fee, but I don't see where money is created (within transactions or within some reward) well enough to quantify the offsetting amount...if this whole way of thinking in terms of "total money supply change" is flawed, I hope someone can explain.

Comment: You need to factor the block reward too -> check this post on Alchemy for instance: https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/how-to-calculate-ethereum-miner-rewards

Comment: @DrGorilla.eth I have been mentioning "reward" from the start...and now you say the same thing plus it gets upvoted...I am losing confidence here in eth by the day.

Comment: you mention "since rewards are mostly (entirely?) paid with gas fees", this is NOT the same thing as a reward given to the validator, the "block reward", when producing a new block (it does not comes from gas fee) - please see the link

Comment: 3 things you need to consider: block reward ("inflation", given to the validator, for a given block), tip (part of the gas of a tx, given to validator as a "bribe"), base fee (mandatory part of the gas of a tx, burn). Their equilibrium is, iiuc, what you're trying to grasp